# How should a large publishing client handle multiple brokers?

Tags: mqtt

From reading the spec, it appears each client should keep a list of brokers, so that client can move to the next broker if it loses connection.  I’m wondering if there is a convention to follow when selecting the next broker to use.  For example, should I always run sequentially through the list, or should I perhaps have an order of preference?

For example, lets say a client has three configured brokers.  It starts by connecting to broker #1.  Later it loses that connection and connects to broker #2.  If it loses connection to #2, is it typical to try #1 again (as a preferred broker) or try #3 then #1?  Or, should it publish to all configured brokers simultaneously?

My specific use case is a large EoN node handling data for potentially thousands of devices.

Comment: This question can only lead to opinion based answers (and as such off topic for StackOverflow) as there is no definitive answer. It shouldn't matter how you choose the next fail over broker

Comment: @hardillb I'm just wondering if there is a convention the community has come to accept.